# Is it safe to format a partition on which Ubuntu is installed (I want to reinstall) when in dualboot with Windows?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I have a partition on which Ubuntu is installed and I want to reinstall it as well as increase space on that partition. So since I have to modify the partition, I can't just boot from Live USB and select the option 'erase old version of Ubuntu, install new'. I know there are, like, relatively simple ways to unmount the partition and increase its size but formatting the partition, since I do actually need to wipe all data on it, seems like a considerably easier option that I can do from Windows (as well as increase the partition size). Obviously, I backed up the files that I need. The only thing I'm wondering about is if it won't wreak havoc on my existing Windows installation? Can, I don't know, grub act up and not let me boot anything? I plan to format the partition, increase its size, then immediately launch Live USB and install Ubuntu. I'm fairly sure I actually did this several years ago and it was fine but now I'm getting worried so I thought I'd ask...

Comment: UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR? And generally you only use Windows tools to modify Windows partitions & Linux tools to modify Linux. If booting using grub, deleting Linux partition will break booting as menu is in the partition. Only start of boot is in MBR (BIOS) or ESP (UEFI). You do not need to delete anything. Just check to format box using Something Else install option.  And best to use Something Else when dual booting and reinstalling.

Comment: You'll likely want to start with cleaning up grub (and shim) from your ESP (and NVRAM) or MBR first. Once you revert to the "pure Windows boot path", every non-Windows-related partition should be "safe" to delete. That also prevent the new installation from being possibly tainted by any leftover.

Comment: @oldfred UEFI. I don't quite get what you mean, do you suggest I: allocate a new partition (extra space which I want to add to my Linux partition), do nothing to the old one, boot from Live USB and select 'Something Else'? I hoped my question would showcase that I'm very much a noob here and scared to break anything...

Comment: If not immediately reinstalling, you need to follow Tom Yan's advice. If reinstalling immediately with Something Else you  can do anything you want. Use existing partition, resize partition. But only use Windows to resize NTFS partitions. I prefer to partition in advance with gparted, but that is not required. https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation & https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu You may want to consider smaller / of 30GB & large /home for your data.